# Relation between algebraic hyper de Rham cohomology and hodge theory in positive characteristic

Tags: algebraic-geometry, differential-geometry, homology-cohomology, hodge-theory

I have recently been looking at algebraic de Rham cohomology of curves in positive characteristic. In particular, I am looking at when the sequence
$$0 \rightarrow H^0(X,\Omega_X) \rightarrow H^1_{dR}(X/k) \rightarrow H^1(X,{\mathcal O}_X) \rightarrow 0 $$
doesn't split (where $k$ is an algebraically closed field of characteristic $p \geq 0$).

I was told that this relates to Hodge theory, and I was considering looking in to this for a postgraduate seminar series we have.

However, I couldn't find a direct link to the algebraic de Rham theory (emphasis on the algebraic), and I am not sure of it's relation to Hodge theory.

I wondered whether anyone might be able to recommend some introductory materials/"light" reading. In particular, material that doesn't/minimally covers the analytic side, and relates to algebraic geometry.

Comment: One of the results of Hodge theory (for a smooth compact Kähler manifold) is that $H^q (M, \Omega^p)$ is isomorphic to the space $\mathcal{H}^{p,q} (M)$ of harmonic $(p, q)$-forms, and moreover that $H^n (M, \mathbb{C})$ is isomorphic to $\oplus_{p + q = n} \mathcal{H}^{p, q}$. For $M$ of dimension 1 (i.e. a curve), this says $H^1 (M, \mathbb{C})$ is isomorphic to $H^0 (M, \Omega^1) \oplus H^1 (M, \Omega^0)$. Is that what you are looking for?

Comment: Hi @ZhenLin I think that is along the right lines, but unfortunately I forgot to mention that  was particularly looking in positive characteristic, which I guess will change things somewhat. Sorry!